# How to Loop randomly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
$rowCount = 40 ; 
for (var $j = 0; $j < $rowCount -1; $j++) {
    var currentNum = #something
}
```

I need to have a mechanism, where I can loop in a way that I will be applying the values to the `currentNum` in a random way.

Eg: At the end of the loop, the `currentNum` should have the value `(0....39)`. But it shouldn't be applied starting from `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.....39`.

It should be applied in a random way like `39, 4, 5,17, 28 , 16 ....` and it should cover all the numbers from `0-40`. I figured this can be achieved using a `HashMap` in java, but how to implement in javascript?

Comment: Look up Fisher-Yates shuffle. What is your Java way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/sp6uvjek/)

Comment: HashMap is not guaranteed to preserve the order. But it might do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = Array(rowCount);
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) numbers[i] = i;

shuffle(numbers); // randomly shuffle array elements

for (var $j = 0; $j < $rowCount -1; $j++) {
    var currentNum = numbers[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var _data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  _data.push(i);
}

var result = [];

_data.slice().forEach(function(){
 result.push(getRandomValue(_data))
});

function getRandomValue(arr,i) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var result = arr[r];
  arr.splice(r, 1);
  return result;
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```